# Windows 10 xCopy Over Network

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-10, batch-file, xcopy

We have a Windows 10 box here that's been running a batch file that runs an xcopy on a folder with subfolders. It's been running happily for years, but last week, on 12th December, for no apparent reason it's started to go slow. As in, 8Mbps across a 100Mbps link.

I've run an iPerf test and that achieves 100Mbps over 60 seconds. I've checked traceroute to see what devices it's hitting on the way across. I've checked Windows Updates for anything that was installed on 12th December, nothing. I've checked the NetSh int tcp settings, nothing. I've added the /J flag on the xCopy command in the hopes that might've done something. Nothing.

I have now hit a brick wall as I cannot see any reason why xCopy would be limited to 8Mbps. If anyone has encountered this before and has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: AV on the workstation scanning the file operation ? or the AV in the remote server ?

Comment: Ah, thanks, disabled A/V on the client, server is A/V disabled already.

Comment: I wouldn't disable the AV complete,y just add the directory/job path to the exclusion list.

Comment: Is that maked a differance ? if so I would add it an a answer

Comment: Clarification; I added the folder in the exclusion list. No difference.